# How to run a script before building codename one project

Tags: ios, cross-platform, codenameone

Is it possible to run a script before building an iOS project using codename one? My objective is to add pod artifactory for pod using pod-art, so the builder will be able to install some private pod packages.

Comment: should this be tagged with Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

But you can create a file with the extension `.podspec` and place it in the `native/ios` directory. It will be used as a standard podspec file and let you install a custom pod.